# Common Lisp function to determine lengths of nested lists in a list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, nested-lists, do-loops

I am only allowed to use the `do` construct, concept which i still can't get a grasp of. I tried the following code, but it returns `nil`.

```
(defun fun(list)
(do ((i 0 (+ i 1)) (l '() (if (listp (nth i list)) (append l (list (length (nth i list)))))))
((null (nth i list)) l)
)
)
```

Is the updated value of `l` wrong? The output for this list `(a (b) (c d))` should be `(1 2)`.

Comment: no, `(fun '(a (b) (c d)))` returns `(1 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to think in terms of lists instead of arrays. You are using the n-th element of a list as if it was an array. Instead, with `do` you can traverse the list by taking the next sublist each time, i.e. dropping the first element and getting another list without that first element.

```
(defun fun(list)
  (do ((l list (cdr l))
       (result nil) )
      ((null l) (nreverse result))
    (if (listp (car l))
      (push (length (car l)) result) )))
```

The `do` operator takes three arguments: the list of variables, the end condition and the body of the loop. The first includes the name of the variables, their initial value and (optionally) how they change from one loop to the next. For example, `(l list (cdr l))` says that you use a variable `l` whose initial value is the input list and from one loop to the next it will become the cdr of itself, i.e. it will lose its first element.
The ending condition includes also the return value of the function. With `((null l) (nreverse result))` we are saying that when the variable `l` is null, the function will end and return the value `(nreverse result)`. Why nreverse? Because we use push in the body, which accumulates values in the wrong order.
Finally, the body tells the function to add to `result` the length of the first element of `l` whenever this is a list.

Comment: `DO` is not a *function*, but a *special operator*.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all the items in `nested-list`. For each one that is a list according to `listp`, calculate the length and collect it. The list of collected lengths is the resulting value:

```
(loop for item in nested-list
      if (listp item) collect (length item))
```

Pass each element `nested-list` into a function. For each item which is a list, the function returns a one-element list of the length, otherwise it returns the empty list. The lists are catenated to form one list, and returned.

```
(mapcan (lambda (x) (if (listp x) (list (length x)))) nested-list)
```

Remove non-list items from `nested-list`, producing a new list which has only lists. Then map this list through the `length` function, resulting in a list of lengths:

```
(mapcar #'length (remove-if-not #'listp nested-list))
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work?

Comment: typo - if (lisp item) should be if (listp item) ?

Comment: @SurajKumar There is no special  trick or algorithm here; some library features (which are thoroughly documented) are being used in rudimentary ways. And if someone is not going to do their own homework, they should at least research on their own how the spoon-fed solutions work (in case they are asked to explain their submission to the prof).

Comment: @Kaz Code-only answers may solve the problem but they are much more useful if you explain how they solve it. Community requires theory as well as code both to understand your answer fully. It was the reason your answer appeared for the review.

Comment: @SurajKumar I will try.